# Validation event not firing

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this very simple viewModel:

```
class ViewModel : IDataErrorInfo
{
    public Producto myProduct { get; set; }
    public string PR { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        myProduct = new Producto { ID = 1, Name = "Product 1" };
        PR = "Test";
    }
    public string Error
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get 
        {
            string sError = "";
            return sError;
        }
    }
}
```

And this simple view:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"   
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">    
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
    <TextBox Height="40" Width="200" Text="{Binding Path=myProduct.Name,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
        <TextBox Height="40" Width="200" Text="{Binding Path=PR,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Can anybody tell me why validation event is fired for property PR but not for myProduct?
I can't manage to validate fields from an exposed object of the viewmodel! Anyone please!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
{Binding Path=myProduct.Name, …
```

For that binding to utilize `IDataErrorInfo`, the type of `myProduct` has to implement `IDataErrorInfo` too. Just like you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for subobjects, you need to implement the error info interface too for each subobject.

Comment: But that force me to implement IDataError on the model (myProduct is the model class)! that doesn't sound like a good idea specially if the model class is behind WCF (like in my real case). Can't i implement it on viewmodel?thanks!

Comment: Yeah, you can’t really reuse your POCO model like that. You will have to either modify your original model, or duplicate it on client-side in an interaction-aware way (INPC and IDEI). What I personally do is make the models virtual (all properties as `virtual` so I can subclass it), and then add the INPC and IDEI implementation using dynamic proxies (e.g. Castle Dynamic Proxy). That works via WCF too, but requires some discipline (e.g. you need to keep the original object around, as you can’t communicate with your subtyped object via WCF).

Comment: Can you give some samples of any of those approachs? Thank you

Comment: Take a look at [this example](http://ayende.com/blog/4106/nhibernate-inotifypropertychanged) on how to implement INPC with Castle DP. Essentially you have to do that for IDEI too.